# Flash Virtual Tour Not Working Correctly

Tags: html, xml, flash, actionscript

I've used third party software to create virtual tour for my clients website. It works perfectly fine on its own, you can see it here http://freshbeer.lv/development/en/virtual_tour/virtual_tour.html

But Once I include virtual_tour.html page on my index page it doesn't work, you can see it here http://freshbeer.lv/development/en

I'm confident that I changed all paths to files correctly, but still it doesn't work. However I can see Gray box that should contain virtual tour, but it doesn't display it, I'm really confused, could anyone please suggest what can be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your SWF is wrong.  The page tries to load it from the same folder where index.html is located.  You can easily see this if you use web developer tools, e.g. in Safari (Activity Window) or Firebug's "Net" view.